# Google Cloud Messaging - Multiple Account Multiple Device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am learning how to implement the `GCM` both from client side (Android) and from server side (`ASP.NET`). I spent a bit of time on reading the whole google documentation related to `GCM` and I also tried the sample that they provided.
Because I need to integrate the `GCM` in an already existing app, I would like to know some specific stuff.

As I got it, the registration id is a token which ties the app on a specific device to the `GCM` service and the app server; so, the backend can send downstream messages directly to that device.

In my scenario, I could have *multiple users* who can use the app on the same device, that means they need to login in the app and they have an account on a database in the server side. Do I need to store a different registration id for each user on that device? Or still the registration id refers to only the app?

And what about the same scenario but distributed on multiple device, because a user can have multiple devices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This relates a lot to the context of your app and what you want to do with notifications

Having one registration ID per device will be okay.

I manage my multiple users by using subscription tags handled by my server.

So take the scenario if you have a sports app:

User A & User B share the same device. Each user subscribes to a tag.

```
User A is subscribed to two tags (Basketball & Football)

User B is subscribed to two tags (Tennis & Basketball)
```

When User A logs out you clear the tags associated with that user and when User B logs in you fetch his/her tags.

Your server knows notifications to send to the device based on the tags the user has subscribed for.

Multiple device scenario:

The same goes, when your user logs In you get their tags. The device also has its own token from GCM.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I was also thinking that it could be only handled by the server. In the database, I can store a relation between users and registration ids, having a field that sets a device active or inactive for a specific user. So, when the server needs to send a downstream message to a specific user, it retrieves all active and associated registration ids and send the notification to all of them in multicast. Could it be?

Comment: This complicates things more, why handle your database ids locally? What if the user wipes all data, then you've lost data for multiple users

Comment: What do you mean with _if the user wipes all data_? The server will store all registration ids sent to it and it will create relations based on accounts. It might be, as said in the other answer, that when another user logins in the app, info has to be sent to server in order to update who is associated to a specific regID.

Answer (score 0):

The registration id is the app's id, it may be changed if app version was updated. Your push notification will be sent on device with your app, regardless user account. So every user on every device will receive your notification, you must store only one refistration id per device.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to send the notification to only a specific user? In the documentation is also reported that "_The request to your server should be authenticated if your app is using accounts._"

Comment: Then you must store current user and it's registration id's, where user log in. The situation with one device and many users: if new user log in, device send info to server, that this user have this registration id The previous user with this registration id must be deleted. If user uses multiple devices - db must store each registration id. And you will send push to known reg id's, which matches your user.

Comment: According to your suggestion, it is better to delete the relation between an user and a regID when another user logins into the app,right?

Comment: I think yes, because your new user will receive notifications, that you want to send to previous user. I think you must store only actual information - user and it's current registration id's.

Answer (score 0):

**For multiple users:** If your messages are user specific, you would want to retrieve the user's token and subscribe to it only while they are logged in. When you switch users remove/unregister the previous token, then save/register the new user's token.

You should not only do this if you have multiple users per device, but when a user signs out. This will prevent user-specific messages being shown at wrong times to wrong users.

**For multiple devices:** it sounds like you are looking for [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications).

> With device group messaging, app servers can send a single message to multiple instance of an app running on devices belonging to a group. Typically, "group" refers a set of different devices that belong to a single user.

This is also nice because of the `collapse_key`. When one of the devices on the same account opens a notification, it will dismiss the notification on the other devices..